# Insert image into borderpane as background

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to load image into BorderPane. I have a static Java method which makes this task more complicated for me:

```
private static final Image iv;    
    static {
        iv = new Image(StartPanel.class.getClass().getResource("/images/system-help.png").toExternalForm());
    }

public static void insert(){

     bp.setCenter(iv);
}
```

Can you tell me how I can load the image properly?

P.S I get this

```
Executing com.javafx.main.Main from /home/rcbandit/Desktop/test/DX-57DC/dist/run1833589211/DX-57DC.jar using platform /opt/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:642)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dx57dc.stages.StartPanel.infrastructureIcon(StartPanel.java:241)
    at com.dx57dc.stages.StartPanel.navigationPanel(StartPanel.java:138)
    at com.dx57dc.stages.StartPanel.agentsPanel(StartPanel.java:78)
    at com.dx57dc.stages.Agents.agentsPanel(Agents.java:9)
    at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC.initMainStage(DX57DC.java:287)
    at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC.start(DX57DC.java:115)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

P.S 2
I managed to load the image with this code:

```
    private static final ImageView iv;    
        static {
            iv = new ImageView(StartPanel.class.getResource("/com/dx57dc/images/6.jpg").toExternalForm());
        }

borderpane.setCenter(iv);
```

Comment: do you mean how to load an image in javafx or this problem to get the image shown?

Comment: Maybe I have these two problems.

Comment: do you want to get the background in center or should it be in all areas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work. You not even need to handle the image load. The trick is to use the style property:

```
borderpane.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"/images/system-help.png\");-fx-background-size: 500, 500;-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;")
```

For sure you should outsource the css file and not use inline styles. It's just easier to show.

If you just want to set the background of the center area use this:

```
borderpane.getCenter().setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"/images/system-help.png\");-fx-background-size: 500, 500;-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;")
```

Note:
The `system-help.png` is located in the `/images` directory, which is at the same level as the class file for the application (e.g. using eclipse it must be stored in the `bin` folder, which means you add a folder (for example call it resources) to your project and use it as a `source folder`, in this folder than you will need the image folder. Kinda weird but thats how `fx` needs it).

Edit: Resize as following:

```
private static final ImageView iv;    
static {
            iv = new ImageView(StartPanel.class.getResource("/com/dx57dc/images/6.jpg").toExternalForm());
            iv.resize(100, 100);
        }
```

Comment: I get NPE when I load image. Maybe I need to use the old way in my post.

Comment: how can you get a NPE? java fx is never throwing a NPE when loading an image via css, its just ignoring the attribute. You must have done something wrong on another place

Comment: NPE will be thrown it `borderpane` is null ord `borderpane.getCenter()` is null, thats some different problem nothing to do with image loading

Comment: mh not much to see in there, can you show your current code, this one with the style property?

Comment: bpi.getCenter().setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(\"../images/6.jpg\"); -fx-background-size: 500, 500; -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;");

Comment: I updated the post. I managed to load the image but now I need to shrink the image because it's too big. How I can do this by using the above code?

Comment: In JavaFX2, I could get: `bp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: GREEN;");` to work, but `bp.getCenter().setStyle("-fx-background-color: RED;");` failed.

I know that the question was on a background image style, but did that second snippet above work in JavaFX 2?
It looks like you should be allowed to set the style on any Node (subject to CSS constraints in: [http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) ).

Comment: Make sure that you establish the local URL from the "Classes" directory if you are using netbeans, it is usually one dir above where the actual compiled class is.